# Overcoming or managing deadband in vehicle steering controller

Tags: control

I found out there is a deadband in my steering controller after several runs. And the transfer function for it in the \$s\$-domain is 
$$
H(s)=\frac{270\cdot e^{-0.03s}}{0.015\cdot s + 1}
$$
To overcome this deadband, should I introduce a compensator ? My control theory background is weak so am not sure of a proper way to manage the deadband.

Comment: Does the period of delay ever vary with time due to load factors changing?  WIth PID feedback, I would increase D gain and consider D^2 or veolicty and acceleration feedback from another sensor or derivative

Comment: @SunnyskyguyEE75 if i use a lateral controller for a lane keeping system for an example, i can manage this problem by increasing the D-gain in that controller. But im looking for a general solution for the steering controller.

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics* djack, but I'm afraid that [cross-posting the same question to multiple sites is not allowed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/64069/138432). If you find a better place to ask your question, please do not just ask your question a second time, instead flag it for the attention of a moderator who can migrate the question for you. Questions which are not considered on topic on the target site will have their migration rejected, but in this case I can assure you it would be accepted.